# cannot import csv to database mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

I make a admin page to upload the csv file into mysql. The file csv has size 59,9mb. But my script didn't upload the file into mysql. Would you mind to help me to fix this problem? Here is my code :

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Admin Update </TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF ?>" method='post'>
<font face=arial size=2>Type file name to import:</font><br>
<input type='file' name='filename' size='20'><br>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'></form>
<?php
include("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");
$connection = mysql_connect ('127.0.0.1', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());} 

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("ipcoba", $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
} 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// address to copy csv file
$target_path = "C:/xampp/htdocs/bikinwebtracert";     

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['filename']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "<font face=arial size=2>The file ". basename( $_FILES['filename']['name']). " Upload Success</font><br>";
} else{
echo "<font face=arial size=2>Failed to Upload, Please try again</font><br>";
}

$filename=$target_path;
$load=mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE $filename INTO TABLE CityBlocks FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 2 LINES (startIpNum, endIpNum, locId)'\n' ") or die(mysql_error());
if ($load){
echo("Failed");
} else {
echo("Success");
}
}
?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I need to fix this problem as soon as possible. Please Help. Thank You.

Comment: Yep, we'd need to see the error you're getting. But my first guess is that you simply need to increase your ini setting for post_max_size above the default of 8M, so your 60M file gets through.

Comment: there's no error. But the file didn't uploaded. Any something wrong?

Comment: @RyanLaBarre, I've changed the default size in php.ini. But it still didn't work. How to fix this?

Comment: Start by isolating the error: Exactly what doesn't work? How far in your code is everything alright? Is the file uploaded? when you know at what line the error is happening, figure out what's wrong and fix it! Make sure you have error logging enabled.

Comment: Right after checking for submit (near "//address for submitting csv"), add print_r($_FILES) - add that output to your question.

Comment: @EmilVikström, I'm sorry. I don't really understand of what you explain. I'm newbie. Can you just explain it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Try to improve your filters, to detect where the error happened

2 - Try to use one name for the csv file (rename the uploaded file to test.csv), To secure yourself, and make sure the file will be uploaded successfully

3 - try to use file_get_contents instead of move_uploaded_file

4 - Make sure when your error happened? error in uploading or in importing?

Try this code:

## Edit

i am glad that you have fixed your problem

i have explained as much as possible, i am sorry for my english

```
<?php

/*
The script idea is
1- we get the file name on the user computer
2- we rename it to import.csv
3- we check if file already exists or not
4- we upload the file
5- import the file
*/

/*
STEP 1
if there is incoming files.
*/
if(!$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']||empty($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']))
    die('Please select a file');
if($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']){
/*
STEP 2
Here we will check if there is import.csv file
if there is import.csv file, that's mean there is a process underway
*/
    if(file_exists('/tmp/import.csv'))
        die('Please wait, we still working on the previous process...');
/*
File path
on the user computer
*/
    $filepath=$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
/*
New path for the file
/tmp folder.. always have a permits that allow the lifting of the file
*/
    $newpath='/tmp/import.csv';
/*
Get the content of the file
read more about file_get_contents()
*/
    $getFile=file_get_contents($filepath);
/*
file_put_contents()
function that's requires to parametrs #1 file name #2 file content
and it will create a file with the name and content that you have provided
*/
    $uploade=(!empty($getFile))?file_put_contents($newpath,$getFile):die('We cant get the file!');
/*
if file exists we have succeed
*/
    if(!file_exists($newpath))
        die('The file did not uploaded..');

    //import to database
    $load = mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL .........");
    if($load){
        //remove the file..
        unlink($newpath);
        echo 'success...';
    }

    else{
        echo(file_exists($getFile))?'File uploaded but did not imported to mysql':'File not uploaded';
    }

}



?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't really understand of your 1-4 steps. Can you just explain to me step by step to do? I'm newbie and I'm a little hard to understand. Thank You.

Comment: for "'/tmp/import.csv'", is the import.csv the file I try to upload?? Then can I replace it with variable $filename like I post the question above in query load data?? I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding with your real explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to import the file into mysql through the command line with that import command?  Try that first to make sure it is working before investigating the rest of the code.

Edit:

According to [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), if it is successful it should return TRUE or a resource on success or FALSE if not success.  Your code has this:

```
if ($load){
    echo("Failed");
} else {
    echo("Success");
}
```

I think there may be a logic error.  Try changing the code to this and tell us what happens:

```
$load=mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE $filename INTO TABLE CityBlocks FIELDS  TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 2 LINES (startIpNum, endIpNum, locId)'\n' ");
if (!$load){
    echo mysql_error();
} else {
echo("Success");
}
```

Comment: I've never tried to upload via command line. But I've tried to upload it via phpmyadmin with the query "load data local..." and it's done. but when I try to make the interface like I've posted above. the file cannot upload and import. Any suggest?

Comment: Alrighty, when the load is run it has mysql_error().  What does that print out?

Comment: I'm sorry for asking. where I have to run the mysql_error? in php or phpmyadmin (mysql)? If I run the mysql_error in phpmyadmin, there's no error. It successfully import to the table.

Comment: in php also there's no mysql_error. but the data didn't upload and import to the table. How this could be fix?? Thank You.

Comment: @chumyee, I updated the post.  Please see if the latest comment helps :)

Comment: I've tried your suggest. But nothing works. I've checked by the console of browser. There's no error. When I run your code after I've chosen the file then the page still the same like the first we called the page. No notifications of error. Is that awkward? Or I just don't know how to fix?

Comment: Is it displaying Success or Failure?  If not, maybe it is failing before it hits that line.

Comment: Nothing display on my page. So could you give me another way to fix this Rachael?

Comment: You'll need to debug it line by line.  Verify it is connecting to the database, that it is using the right database, that the filepath is correct, that the load command is executing correctly.  Xdebug may be helpful to you.  Otherwise you're basically gonna have to echo the variables to make sure they are what you want, execute the line and check the output.  Use echo to print and die to stop the script and do this line by line until you isolate the error.  It's time consuming, but you should be able to find it pretty quickly.